# OCCI with GCC in SOLARIS

Tags: oracle, unix, solaris, occi

We are trying to use OCCI with GCC. OCCI is compiled using sun studio compiler. Is there any possibility to use OCCI with GCC instead of sun native compiler CC?

Comment: You have to try it. c++ ABI is complex, and there can be gotchas.

Comment: Apart from third party library, do we have any Oracle libraries to overcome this problem?

Comment: Mine personal opinion is, that it is better to use any other open-source C++ around OCI. Than OCCI.

Comment: Can suggest any open source library which is best among other?

Comment: Check these: https://www.openhub.net/p/ocipl , http://soci.sourceforge.net/

Comment: It's true, there are better C++ libraries for interacting with Oracle DBs that don't have such ABI compatibility issues. For example, [OTL](http://otl.sourceforge.net) is header-only and open-source, thus you aren't bound to a particular C++ compiler or STL version when using it.

Answer (score 0):

You effectively can not mix multiple C++ run-time libraries.

A C++ run-time implementation is extremely complex.  This posting explains some of the complexity:

[Stability of the C++ ABI: Evolution of a Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/stablecplusplusabi-333927.html#runtime)

> **The C++ ABI**
>
> The C++ ABI includes the C ABI. In addition, it covers the following
>   features:
>
> - Layout of hierarchical class objects, that is, base classes and virtual base classes
> - Layout of pointer-to-member
> - Passing of hidden function parameters (for example, this)
> - How to call a virtual function:
>
>   - Vtable contents and layout
>   - Location in objects of pointers to vtables
>   - Finding adjustment for the this pointer
> - Finding base-class offsets
> - Calling a function via pointer-to-member
> - Managing template instances
> - External spelling of names ("name mangling")
> - Construction and destruction of static objects
> - Throwing and catching exceptions
> - Some details of the standard library:
>
>   - Implementation-defined details
>   - typeinfo and run-time type information
>   - Inline function access to members

You can also add in different C++ compilers implement name-mangling differently, making it effective impossible to use OCCI directly with GCC on Solaris.

You might be able get something working, but anything you do will be extremely fragile at best.  The next OS or C++ run-time-update could break things, and you may not be able to fix the problem.

Unless you're writing very simple applications, I strongly recommend just using the Solaris Studio compiler - and getting familiar with the entire suite of tools that include performance profiling, memory checking, and even race-condition detection, most of which is in my opinion superior to the tools used with GCC.

Comment: The Solaris Studio (SS) compiler misses several GCC features, e.g. it has nothing that comes close to GCC's warnings mode. There is no stack-protector, no fortify-source support. If you compare GCC/Linux Studio/Solaris, GCC's different sanitizers (address, undefined behavior, ...) for memory checking, race-condition detection, etc. are definitely superior to what you get with SS. Similar things can be said about the profiling. In addition, SS struggles to support current C++ standards and catch up with GCC extensions.

Comment: @maxschlepzig *are definitely superior to what you get with SS* At least I clearly stated my preference was an opinion and didn't confuse it with a fact.  FWIW, last I looked GCC on SPARC still lacked any equivalent to something like  [`-xmemalign=1i`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5265/bjavc/index.html), so the bar for writing working code on SPARC is much higher using GCC.